# What to consider when deciding spark-structured-streaming vs microservice, both reading data from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, microservices, spark-streaming

We need to create a new application, that needs to read data from Kafka and push data into oracle db, which will be used by a UI based application.

We did Spike on both microservice and spark structured-streaming.
Both fulfills our requirement.

So we are not sure which one to select. 
Are these any standards which we must consider to decide whether to go for a microservice or for 
spark-structured-streaming application?

Thanks

Anuj

Comment: One of our concern was offset management. But following link provides good insight about the same: https://blog.cloudera.com/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/

Comment: There is a project [HyperDrive](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hyperdrive) that seems it could help, as in you don't have to write anything on your own. Or go and check their code. Might serve as inspiration

Comment: Do you already have a spark environment? Will you be using a PaaS spark? Spark will have operational over head if you want to do it yourself.